# Neural Networks for predicting Energy at particular date

Tags: neural-networks, forecasting, deep-learning, backpropagation, artificial-intelligence

I am trying to predict Solar Energy value at particular date.So,for this I am applying Artificial Neural Networks model.I am having problem in deciding activation function. Since sigmoid function gives me output 0-1 but I want output something like 256.33. So I thought to apply sigmoid for hidden layer and ReLu for output layer to keep non-linearity in networks.Can you suggest me what is the way to do this?What I am doing is correct?

Comment: Can you post your architecture of the network? What is the input data looks like?

Comment: Well I can describe the data.-1)It contains 12 features data for 98 Oklahoma grid sites.(2)Data set contains information about temperature,humidity,irradiance and some other required information.(3)It contains weather information of 144 grid sites and I have to predict Energy for 98 grids out of 144. @AlexanderYau

Comment: About my Architecture-I am using 3 layers one hidden layer.(1) I tried to apply sigmoid for both the layers as activation function.(2)Then I applied ReLU activation for both the function. These two methods were failure. Now I am trying to apply ReLU on output layer and Sigmoid for hidden layer.

Comment: @Abhishek It is a one way that you can use a neural network for a regression problem. [This](https://deeplearning4j.org/linear-regression) describes what you are trying to do.